# Add datetime column with default value

Tags: python, alembic

I'm trying to write an alembic migration to add a datetime column to a table. I want all existing rows to have a default time of right now and future rows to default to the time they were created.  I've tried `server_default='now()'`, which sets all existing rows to right now, but new rows seem to get this same time.  How do I set the default so new rows get the current time?

Answer (score 26):

The issue is that the default is set to the *result* of `now()`, not the *execution* of it, so the default will be the exact time it was set, rather than the current time at insert.  Use `sa.func.current_timestamp()` to set it to that function, rather than the result of that function.

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('my_table', sa.Column('my_column', sa.DateTime,
            server_default=sa.func.current_timestamp()))
```